# Not giving output for gdal_translate

Tags: python, gdal-translate, subset

I am using following code to take subset of all files in a folder. The code is not giving any error but it is not creating output files. How to solve it?

```
import numpy as np
import re
import gdal
import ogr
from osgeo import gdal_array
from gdalconst import *
import os
import osr
import subprocess
e=1
indir = '/home/vigna/Documents/polynyas/SIC/2017/Sept'
directory=os.fsencode(indir)
for file in os.listdir(directory):    
    file1=os.fsdecode(file)
    if file1.endswith(".tif"):
        ds = gdal.Open(os.path.join(indir,file1),GA_ReadOnly)
        out=str(e)+'_subset.tif'
        inputf = file1# input raster
        #print(len(inDS))
        inDS=str(inputf[0:33])
        #print(inDS)
        outDS = out# output raster
        #print(outDS)
        ulx = -161255
        uly = 2971737
        lrx = 437613
        lry = 2475328
        translate = 'gdal_translate -projwin %s %s %s %s %s %s' %(ulx, uly, lrx, lry, inDS, outDS)
        #print(translate)
        os.system(translate)
        e+=1
```

Comment: not the exact solution, but you should try with subprocess.call instead of os.system. And check the message of the "printed" command line + use full path for the output file name.

Comment: Try using `subprocess` as @radouxju indicated. If you do it like suggested [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/274828/use-osgeo4w-shell-command-from-python-2-7-script/276228#276228), you should see something, especially when you drop the `if` and print `stdout` and `sdterr` no matter what `p.returncode` is

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling the system's gdal_translate binary from within the python environment and passing to it a python (type = gdal.Dataset) object, which it does not recognize as a valid format (gdalinfo --formats for the supported list). For what you are doing, you do not need to import/use the python bindings, but simply build the command in python and pass it off to the OS. This version of your code should work:

```
import os,sys
e=1
indir = '/home/vigna/Documents/polynyas/SIC/2017/Sept'
directory=os.fsencode(indir)
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    file1=os.fsdecode(file)
    if file1.endswith(".tif"): # I would check the file type this way: "if os.path.splitext(file1)[1] =='.tif':"
        inputf = file1# input raster
        out=str(e)+'_subset.tif' # I would retain the original filename for clarity i.e. "out = os.path.basename(file1).splitext[0]+'_subset.tif'"
        ulx = -161255
        uly = 2971737
        lrx = 437613
        lry = 2475328
        translate = 'gdal_translate -projwin %s %s %s %s %s %s' %(ulx, uly, lrx, lry, file1, out)
        os.system(translate)
        e+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think @planetsandman has you covered, but I wanted to add that you can debug these system calls yourself if you use

```
import subprocess
translate = 'your cmd line call string'
proc = subprocess.Popen(translate, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout,stderr=proc.communicate()
```

The `stdout` variable will contain the output of the call, and the `stderr` variable will contain any error messages.